# Unhide hidden app purchases on iOS 14.2

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, ipados

I have hidden a number of app purchases, and I would now like to unhide them. If you go to the App Store (iOS 14.2), tap your profile picture and go to account settings, you can click "Hidden Purchases" to see a list. The text below the link even says "Unhide purchases that you have previously hidden."

If you go to this list, however, you can only download those purchase. Searching claims you should be able to swipe to the left to unhide them, but the app does not respond to any form of swiping on those icons (both iPad and iPhone).

Is there any way to unhide certain purchases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201322

> You can't unhide an app on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, but you can redownload an app. You don't have to buy the app again.

Comment: Nuts! Thank you. I will accept the answer in 9 minutes when the site allows me. :)

Comment: With Big Sur coming, those with Macs will be able to manage this even better over time. The Mac app should help you expose all these apps if you have that option.

Comment: And if you want to be able to unhide an app - then you can download iTunes on Windows, which still have the feature.

Comment: @bmike This is not correct; I have an M1 Mac and cannot unhide or even see the iOS / iPadOS apps I've hidden.

Comment: Thank you @anahata I’m not sure how the App Store on macOS interacts with the normal iOS App Store functions. When I answered this I was thinking we only needed iPad / iPhone to consider…